# Updating user email in SSO RegistrationHandler without triggering confirmation

Tags: email, user, single-sign-on

I'm working on Single Sign on with Azure Active Directory / Office 365 using OpenID Connect.

User emails in AD are sometimes updated for marriage, divorce, or personal preference.

From my testing, once SSO has been setup for the user, Salesforce automatically uses the existing third-party account link to authenticate the user, so the difference in email is not an issue for login.

However, I would like to use login as an opportunity to update the SFDC Users `email` field

I'm able to update `email` via my `RegistrationHandler` but this triggers the notification to the user which requires them to click the link to update the email.

While this is understandable, I would prefer to be able to silence this notification for this specific use case.

Is there any method, black-tab option, etc, that could allow for this?